# Changing all table cell properties from appDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have several UITableViews and what I would like to do is to be able to change the properties of those UITableViews from a single class, which is the AppDelegate class.

Does anyone know if it would be possible to do so?

Comment: plz Visit this link
<http://stackoverflow.com/a/11031405/1223137>

Comment: it is possible but not such a clever way, you should chose inheritance instead. also take a look at [this](http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are using iOS5 then you can use UIAppearance

```
//For example this changes the background color of all UITableViews contained in a UIView
[[UITableView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIView class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```